# For mobius map why we need a invertible matrix of determinant $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

The map $T:\mathbb{C}_\infty\to \mathbb{C}_\infty $ defined by  $T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  is called Mobius map . My question is why we may assume $ad-bc=1$ ? If $p\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\},$ then $\frac{paz+pb}{pcz+pd}=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$

Comment: I don't know why people just down vote question. I have some conceptual problem in this question. That's why I have posted this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple calculation. As you already saw in your question, if you scale $a, b, c, d$ by a common nonzero factor $p$, you don't change the function:
$$
\frac{az+b}{cz+d} = \frac{paz+pb}{pcz+pd}
$$
for all $z$. But that change alters the nonzero number $ad - bc$ by the square factor $p^2$:
$$
(pa)(pd) - (pb)(pc) = p^2(ad - bc).
$$
Since all nonzero numbers in $\mathbf C$ have square roots, we can *choose* $p$ so that $p^2 = 1/(ad - bc)$.  Then $p^2(ad - bc) = 1$.

Comment: From your answer it is not really clear to me that why we need $ad-bc=1.$

Comment: @jaysrikrishna You question is why we "may" normalise in this way, and of course it is possible. The reason we do is first that it is convenient to have a single representative out of all the possible forms of a particular function: this particular normalisation turns ut to be computationally convenient - for example when maps are composed.

Comment: Your question asks why we may assume the determinant is $1$. Your title asks why we need the determinant to be $1$. I was answering what the question actually asked.